# Object Builder Exception while using Enterprise Liabrary

Tags: wcf, exception, enterprise-library

I have an WCF application which has seperate client and server application. When I running the application runs fine, but when I try to unit test the application methods the object builder exception is generated. Can somebody help?

[image: This Is Error Message]

Comment: Share some code, or at least the exception message and stack trace. Without it there's no way to help you. Also, since this is entlib, the relvant parts of your web.config/app.config files would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check your test setting of your test project. You have to mention the necessary files that are required for the deployment. Also check whether the test.testsettings file is included in the project and it is properly configured.